# How to resolve playbook error while executing a git module

Tags: git, ansible

My playbook:

```
hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  name: install maven
    apt:
      name: maven
      state: present
  name: taking code from github repository
    git:
      repo: 'https://github.com/LAKSHMIJODI/game-of-life.git'
      dest: /home/ansible/march
      clone: yes
  name: create a war file
    shell: mvn clean install package
```

And the error showing like this:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [install maven]
ok: [localhost]

TASK [taking code from github repository] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable git in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"}

PLAY RECAP
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I edited your title to be more explaining what you actually want to achieve. Also edited the text as it contained a lot of stuff that was not needed or was unclear in what you wanted to explain. I hope that helps to understand your question way better now.

Comment: "*Failed to find required executable git*" You don't have `git`. Create a task to install `git` first. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+install+git

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Failed to find required executable git"*

A: Install git. Also fix the indentation. See [Intro to Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#intro-to-playbooks)

```
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: install maven
    apt:
      name: maven
      state: present
  - name: taking code from github repository
    git:
      repo: 'https://github.com/LAKSHMIJODI/game-of-life.git'
      dest: /home/ansible/march
      clone: yes
  - name: create a war file
    shell: mvn clean install package
```

Test the syntax of the playbook. You should see couple of problems

```
shell> ansible-lint playbook.yml
[401] Git checkouts must contain explicit version
playbook.yml:8
Task/Handler: taking code from github repository

[301] Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing
playbook.yml:13
Task/Handler: create a war file

[305] Use shell only when shell functionality is required
playbook.yml:13
Task/Handler: create a war file
```

Details of the problems are out of the scope for this question and answer. See details in [Ansible Lint Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/#ansible-lint-documentation). If you are not able to solve the problems open new questions for particular problems.